# Testing one set of parameters one times using genetic algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I'm using the genetic algorithm (function ga in Matlab) to find optimum values of parameters of some algorithm. Calculating quality of this algorithm for one set of parameters is time-consuming, but is precise enough, that it isn't necessary to repeat it. But ga testing one set of parameters many times and that is big trouble for me. Is it possible somehow to change it?

Comment: "But ga testing one set of parameters many times and that is big trouble for me" What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (to what I *believe* your question is asking - which is, "How do I speed up computations when the same function that takes a long time to run is called with the same parameters many times?") would be [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), which would allow you to return the results of repeated computations very quickly; something like this:

```
function output = myAlgorithm(inputs)
    % inputs is a cell array

    persistent memos;

    bFoundMemo = false;
    for ii = 1:length(memos)
        if all(cellfun(@eq, memos(ii).inputs, inputs))
            % Found a memo!
            output = memos(ii).output;
            bFoundMemo = true;
            break;
        end
    end

    if bFoundMemo
        disp('Memo found for given inputs. Returning...');
        % Nothing to do!
        return;
    else
        disp('No memo found for given inputs. Computing...');

        % No memo; do computation
        output = myAlgorithmInner(inputs);

        % Store a memo so we don't have to do it again
        sMemo = struct();
        sMemo.inputs = inputs;
        sMemo.output = output;
        if isempty(memos)
            memos = sMemo;
        else
            memos = [memos; sMemo];
        end
    end
end

function output = myAlgorithmInner(inputs)
    % The real work goes here
    output = inputs{1} + inputs{2}; % a simple example
end
```

An example call:

```
>> myAlgorithm({1 2})
No memo found for given inputs. Computing...

ans =

     3

>> myAlgorithm({1 2})
Memo found for given inputs. Returning...

ans =

     3
```

Obviously, you should modify the input/output signature and code that checks for an existing memo to match your algorithm.

You may also want to add a maximum length for the list of memos - if it gets too long, the time to find an existing memo might become comparable to the computation time of your algorithm! Another way to solve this issue would be to store the memos in, e.g., a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/map-containers.html), which would speed up searching for existing memos in a long list.